heroku.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
Not able to use Heroku CLI in VS code. get error "heroku.cmd"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
Many people say to uninstall and install again, then restart and this does not work.
Also, some say to add to path and this has not worked.
I have searched for help in Heroku and Stackoverflow and the above solutions were suggested and have not worked.
Any suggestions that anyone would have will be greatly appreciated.
thanks
Do not see help in the support on Heroku and no one to talk to at Heroku!

trying "heroku --version" gets the same error

Heroku CLI works on my MS Surface but not on work office desktop
